# Error installing bcrypt using bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am going to install some gems in my rails application using bundle install on Debian testing(stretch). I get this error:

```
Installing bcrypt 3.1.10 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20151208-29851-hg3bi3bcrypt-3.1.10/gems/bcrypt-3.1.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20151208-29851-hg3bi3bcrypt-3.1.10/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/bcrypt-3.1.10/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

but I have installed `bcrypt` and `bcrypt-ruby` using `gem install` .

Comment: Can you mention the OS you are running? Some header files need to be installed in case of some OS versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For gems with C extensions to compile, you'll need to install the `ruby-dev` package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Comment: Do you also have the `build-essential` package installed?